# .NET Core 5.0 Cant Connect ElasticSearch Via Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, docker-compose

i am trying to connect ElasticSearch with my .NET Core project. I can send request and create data if i run my project manually. But if i try with the docker build it throws 500 error. I cant create data. It doesnt create elasticSearch index too. When i manually create index and send request, it doesnt create data  either.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY ./*.csproj /app

RUN dotnet restore ./*.csproj
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish ./*.csproj -c Release -o out 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:7000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT docker
EXPOSE 7000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","ElasticDocker.dll"]
```

DockerCompose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  elasticdocker:
   container_name: orhanelasticdeneme
   restart: always
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
   ports: 
    - "7000:7000"
   depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
   networks:
    - es-network

  elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.0.0
   container_name: elasticsearch
   restart: always
   environment:
    - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - discovery.type=single-node
   ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
   ports:
    - "9200:9200"
   networks:
    - es-network

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0
    restart: always
    environment:
     SERVER_NAME: kibana.example.org
     ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
    - es-network

networks:
  es-network:
   driver: bridge
```

I can connect Kibana too btw.

[image]

Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(
           p =>
           {
               var elastic = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(Configuration["elasticsearchserver:Host"]))
               .BasicAuthentication(Configuration["elasticsearchserver:Username"], Configuration["elasticsearchserver:Password"]));
               var userIndex = elastic.Indices.Exists(Configuration["elasticsearchserver:Orhan"].ToString());
               if (!userIndex.Exists)
               {
                   elastic.Indices.Create(Configuration["elasticsearchserver:Orhan"].ToString(), ci => ci.Index(Configuration["elasticsearchserver:Orhan"].ToString()).UserMapping().Settings(s => s.NumberOfShards(3).NumberOfReplicas(1)));
               }               
               return elastic;
           });
```

AppConfig.json

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "elasticsearchserver": {
        "Host": "http://localhost:9200",
        "Username": "guest",
        "Password": "guest",
        "Orhan": "orhan"
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Controller.cs

```
  private readonly IElasticClient _elasticClient;

        public UserController(IElasticClient elasticClient)
        {
            _elasticClient = elasticClient;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(User user)
       {
            var response = await _elasticClient.CreateAsync(user, x => x.Index("orhan").Id(user.Id));
            return Ok(response);           
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<User>(x =>
           x.Index("orhan")
           .From(0)
           .Size(2000)
           );
            return Ok(response.Documents.ToList());
        }
        [HttpGet("/a")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            return Ok("sadgasfdgasd");
        }
```

This is the error in cmd.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect elasticsearch with docker, change your host to container name.

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "elasticsearchserver": {
        "Host": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
        "Username": "guest",
        "Password": "guest",
        "Orhan": "orhan"
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```